# Join several mySQL tables to one table

Tags: mysql, join

I currently have 3 tables, which I am hoping to join into one so I can output the result as a table on the front-end of my group's website. If I had started out with my current goal in mind my tables would be structured differently, but the need for this particular joined table came much later.

Here are simplified versions of my 3 tables...

**TABLE volunteers** contains the following data:

```
primary_id_field    volunteer_id    volunteer_first volunteer_last  supervisor_id   volunteer_added
1                   38              John            Smith           19              1421340096
2                   21              Adam            Jones           7               1421421478
3                   45              Jane            Doe             11              1421424066
```

**TABLE global_members** contains the following data

```
    primary_id_field    member_id   member_first    member_last member_title_id
    15                  7           Alex            Kyles       1
    16                  11          Bryan           Johnson     1
    17                  19          Melissa         Thomas      1
    18                  21          Adam            Jones       2
    19                  38          John            Smith       2
    21                  45          Jane            Doe         2
```

**TABLE groups** contains the following data

```
primary_id_field    title_id    title_name
1                   1           HCJ
2                   2           GMU
3                   3           YCM
4                   4           QTB
```

What I am hoping for as a result of some clever joins is the following data set

```
volunteer_title volunteer_first volunteer_last  supervisor_title    supervisor_first    supervisor_last volunteer_added
YCM             Adam            Jones           HCJ                 Alex                Kyles           1421421478
QTB             John            Smith           HCJ                 Melissa             Thomas          1421340096
WTB             Jane            Doe             GMU                 Bryan               Johnson         1421424066
```

This way I will be able to display something like "*YCM A.Jones assigned to HCJ A.Kyles on 16 JAN 2015*" and list out all of the volunteers with a while loop (talking PHP).

I have had some luck with joining tables in the past so I know the general idea.

I am thinking I will be joining the volunteers table with the others. I can get the first 3 columns no problem, but where I am really struggling is how I can also pull in the additional data about the supervisor, based solely on the supervisor_id field.

Any help will be very much appreciated.

Comment: Add your best effort to your question and explain what exactly stops you from going any further.

Comment: See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query